# SQL Query needed if search criteria is longer than column value

Tags: sql

I have a following sample table structure

| Name | Address |
| --- | --- |
| Name1 | Address1 |
| Name2 | Address2 |

I need to get the Name1 but my search criteria is longer than the column value.

Sample query

```
SELECT * 
FROM SampleTable 
WHERE Name = 'Name1Me'
```

I have tried truncating the search criteria until I get a match like below

```
SELECT * 
FROM SampleTable 
WHERE Name = 'Name1Me'
```

if no result then

```
SELECT * 
FROM SampleTable 
WHERE Name = 'Name1M'
```

if no result then

```
SELECT * 
FROM SampleTable 
WHERE Name = 'Name1M'
```

Result okay

But this will make a lot of queries if the search criteria is much longer than the column value.

I'm asking if there's a better query for situations like this.

Edit:
I'm using MariaDB 10.3 on a Raspberry Pi 3B+.

By better, I mean if there's a single query for this or if it's possible to do this in less queries.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? What exactly would constitute "*better*" for you? A reduction in the amount of required queries? Something else?

Comment: @esqew I edited the question to answer your question. and yes if there's a way to reduce the number of queries or if can be done in a single query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this - reducing the right operand to the length of the left operand:

```
SELECT * 
FROM SampleTable 
WHERE Name = left('Name1Me',char_length(Name))
```

But beware:

1. The actual string functions to use may change depending on the database vendor (you have not tagged), and/or if you use some international character sets.
2. You need to make sure that the length of the search criteria and the length of the column value do not result in invalid function calls (zero length strings, for example).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming by "best match" we mean the longest matching substring from the beginning which does not exceed the length of the predicate string.

If the "does not exceed" part of that doesn't apply (i.e. Name1MEXXXXXXXXXXXXXX is a better match than Name1M to Name1ME) then tinazmu is of course what you should do.

Fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/JjC-YWoY

```
create table some_test_data 
  (
    some_text varchar(255)
  );

insert into some_test_data values('Name1');
insert into some_test_data values('Name1M');
insert into some_test_data values('Name1MEXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');

select *
  from some_test_data a
 order
    by length(REGEXP_SUBSTR('Name1ME',concat('^',some_text))) desc
 limit 1;

/*
some_text
Name1M
*/
```